# Access a static variable in jsp from another jsp

Tags: jsp, static-variables

I have two different jsp(like A.jsp & B.jsp) and these are not have relation(like include,etc).
In A.jsp I have a static boolean named isAccess. Can I access A.isAccess from B.jsp?

If yes, please show me the right direction.

Comment: How are you redirecting from page A to B? On submit button click ??

Comment: No I did not redirect. B is for admin only. If admin decided to show the feature to user,he use B.jsp.

Comment: Use either a servlet to store/fetch the variable or define the variable as a context parameter in your web.xml (code to get context parameters from JSP can easily be found if you google for it)

Comment: @Joris, Thanks I have fixed it with new Util class.